# loop through all element in array before displaying alert

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to check an array of usernames and passwords to authenticate user. The code I have stops at every element of the array and displays alert. how can I have it loop through the entire array then show alert.

```
for(i= 0 ; i< user.length; i+=1) {
  if (username === user[i].username && password === user[i].password) {

    alert("Log In Successful");

    document.getElementById("btn").style.display= "none"
    document.getElementById("navbar-user").innerHTML = username;
    modal.style.display= "none";
  } else {
      alert("Username or Password Incorrect")
  }
```

Comment: Do you REALLY store all users and passwords on the client???

Comment: No its just for learning purposes

Comment: Look at Array.some method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you would like to stop when you find the correct username password combination anyways. So your ELSE is breaking the loop because it is executed on every run.

Here is proposal:

```
var success = false;

for(i= 0 ; i< user.length; i+=1) {
  if (username === user[i].username && password === user[i].password) {
     success = true; 
  } 
}

if(success){
    alert("Log In Successful");

    document.getElementById("btn").style.display= "none"
    document.getElementById("navbar-user").innerHTML = username;
    modal.style.display= "none";
}else{
    alert("Username or Password Incorrect"); 
}
```

Now code will run and complete all elements in array, if user is found it will set `success` to `true`, and alter it otherwise it is false by default.

Comment: @rfrieger you are welcome, if it worked well for you please do accept the answer by clicking the check mark.! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more functional approach using `find` to search the `user` array for a match before continuing.

```
let successfulLogin = user.find(u => {
    return u.username === username && u.password === password;
});

if(successfulLogin) {
    alert("Log In Successful");
    document.getElementById("btn").style.display = "none"
    document.getElementById("navbar-user").innerHTML = username;
    modal.style.display = "none";
} else {
    alert("Username or Password Incorrect");
}
```

Comment: You might as well use `.some()` instead of `.find()` if you're not using the matching value from the array.

Answer (score 0):

Using Array some() Method:

```
if (! user.some(u => username === u.username && password === u.password) )
    alert('Username or Password Incorrect');
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are just testing your code including passwords in the client side .

```js
let alertSucc =true;
for(i= 0 ; i< user.length; i+=1) {
  if (username === user[i].username && password === user[i].password) {

      document.getElementById("btn").style.display= "none"
      document.getElementById("navbar-user").innerHTML = username;
      modal.style.display= "none";
  } else {
      alertSucc =false;
      
  } 
}
  alertSucc ? alert("Log In Successful"):alert("Username or Password Incorrect");
```

Comment: This code will fire on every array element.. OP said that he doesn't want that.. cheers

Comment: yeah I'm just testing. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Using a couple returns and moving down your alert outside of the if statement will help because return will kick out of the current iteration of the loop

```
for(i= 0 ; i< user.length; i+=1) {
  if (username === user[i].username && password === user[i].password) {
    alert("Log In Successful");
    document.getElementById("btn").style.display= "none"
    document.getElementById("navbar-user").innerHTML = username;
    modal.style.display= "none";
    return;
  } else {
    console.log("We haven't proven whether true or false.
    return;
  } 
  alert("We did not find proper credentials that were true, and tested all inputs")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear if you want to show SUCCESS on all valid or on 1 valid user?
And I pray that logic never ever reaches the world! :)

```
let userGOOD = [{username: "a", password: "b"}, {username: "a", password: "b"}];
let userBAD = [{username: "a", password: "b"}, {username: "a", password: "c"}];
let test = (username, password) => (user) => username === user.username && 
password === user.password;
let testAB = test("a", "b");
let GOOD = userGOOD.reduce((p, c) => p && testAB(c), true);
let BAD = userBAD.reduce((p, c) => p && testAB(c), true);
```